# Using the same JComponent in multiple panels

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have 3 classes that each extend `JPanel` - `ShopArmorView`, `ShopWeaponView` and `StatView`.

I am trying to add the `StatView` to both `ShopArmorView` and `ShopWeaponView`, however when stats are changed I need the `StatView` components to update in both `ShopArmorView` and `ShopWeaponView`.

As of right now only the last class to have stat view added to it will update, and I know this is due to `JComponent` containers only being able to be held in one container.

How can I make it when I update a value in the `StatView`, that this update will be shown in all classes that have `StatView` added to them?

What I have tried:

I have tried removing, then adding the `StatView`, then validating the panel, whenever I switch view. However this did not work.

Comment: Can you post your code? Do you use the same instance of  `StatView` in both of your other panels?

Comment: Update a model that each `StatView` uses. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Each time you make a change in a value, call an update method on the other view that will fetch data for the first view, or a common model and update the components.

Comment: BTW 1) *"I have 3 classes that each extend `JPanel`"* It is likely that **none** of them should extend `JPanel`. 2) You should consider adding the `StatView` to the parent container of both `ShopArmorView` and `ShopWeaponView` (outside the bounds of either of the latter).